# Hide Navigation Bar in Interface Builder w/ Storyboards

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uistoryboard, xcode5

I have a pretty basic storyboard based app, with a UINavigationController, a main view and a secondary view, both of which are in the navigation hierarchy. I’m currently hiding the navigation bar on the main view by using `setNavigationBarHidden:` as appropriate in `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear`. It seems like there should be a way to do this in Interface Builder, rather than in code. Essentially I’d like the options available in the *Simulated Metrics* options, but not simulated. Does that exist?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the scene for the UINavigationController itself, I suppose you could check the hidden button for the nav bar in the Attributes inspector, but that would make the nav bar hidden for all the view controllers in the navigation stack. But that's not what you want.

To hide the nav bar for an individual view controller using IB, you would need to use a stand alone nav bar for each view controller (e.g., drap and drop a Navigation Bar from the object library in IB). To use a stand alone nav bar in a navigation stack would be more work than programmatically hiding the nav bar.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose that technically is a way to do it in IB, but not exactly what I had in mind (a checkbox to disable for a specific view). I’m pretty sure that such a thing doesn’t exist though, so I’ll accept this one.

Answer (score 4):

Just uncheck the `Attribute Inspector` > `Shows Navigation Bar` in `Attribute Inspector`

[image]